# how to press a key in scheme

Tags: c++, scheme, key

Is this even possible? I tried searching the schemedocumentation but did not find anything useful.

I want to make a program that 'presses' every minute, or any other interval, a key.

If this is not possible in scheme, is it possible in C++? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Not with standard C++, but it's pretty easy in Windows at least.

Comment: There are no "keys" in standard C++. You'll need a platform-specific *terminal* library. It's probably similar in Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scheme, this will depend heavily on the interpreter in use. For example, here's a Racket sample taken from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Simulate_input/Keyboard#Racket), it'll simulate the pressing of the <kbd>k</kbd> key:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define frame (new frame%
                   (label "Example")
                   (width 300)
                   (height 300)))

(define simulate-key-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (define/public (simulate-key key)
      (send this on-char key))

    (define/override (on-char key)
      (displayln (send key get-key-code)))

    (super-new)))

(define canvas
  (new simulate-key-canvas%
       (parent frame)))

(send frame show #t)
(send canvas simulate-key (new key-event% (key-code #\k)))
```

Comment: so the k key is pressed within the frame?

Comment: and is it possible to make your browser or notepad or whatever the frame?

Comment: A [`frame%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/frame_.html) is just a top-level container window, in principle you can put anything you want inside

Comment: ok thank you! Uhm another question:

`(define record-input%
  (class canvas%
    (define /public (get-input)
      (displayIn (send get-key-code))) ; Or out? 
    
    (super-new)))

(define canvas
  (new simulate-key-canvas%
       (parent frame)))`

I want this class to record the input from the keystrokes that I type and that are written to the screen by simulate-key-canvas% class from the original question?

Comment: so basicly I want to get the output of the repl? Because whenever a number is typed, it gets printed out to the repl. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: The code above captures the key press in the context of the frame (not the repl!), as is the frame the one that can detect such events. The `on-char` handles this event, and in this case, prints it with `displayln` . It's up to you to decide what to do when a key is pressed inside the frame, write the code for `on-char` as you see fit

Comment: I fixed it like this:
`(define/override (on-char key)
      (send keys-pressed add-keys (send key get-key-code)))
   
(define keys-pressed%
  (class object%
    (define lst '())
    
    (define/public (get-lst)
      lst)
    
    (define/public (add-keys key)
      (unless (eq? key 'release)
        (set! lst (cons key lst))))
    
    (define/public (delete-used-key)
      (unless (null? lst)
        (set! lst (cdr lst))))
    
    (super-new)))
   `

Is this a good way? or would you do it otherwise? 

thank you!

Comment: Whatever suits your needs! I'm not entitled to an opinion ;)